# how to load JSP on Lightbox jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, lightbox

I want to display JSP Pages on LightBoxes. 
How and What are the best jQuery API for this purpose!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do that. From the lightbox website:

> Lightbox is a simple, unobtrusive script used to overlay images on top
>   of the current page. It's a snap to setup and works on all modern browsers.

Lightbox is for *images*, not webpages. A rough equivalent are iframes, although I wouldn't recommend using them. Think of a more appropiate implementation for what you are trying to do.